# CSS code for Fiore theme on Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to adjust the CSS code for the Fiore theme on Wordpress. My URL is theuniversalasian.wordpress.com. It is an upgraded premium wordpress account.

With the upgrade, I am able to edit the CSS, but a number of problems are happening. If you could help me with the code, I'd appreciate it!

1. I want to make a white background for the post texts. When I do that, it moves the date, comments, edit links on the left side. I would like those to stay up top near the post title ribbon. At the moment, the site does not show the changes I wanted because I keep fiddling with the code....
2. If possible, I'd like the white background for the text to have rounded corners....
3. The left column somehow loses the graphics....There should be a top cherry blossom graphic like the original theme (http://fioredemo.wordpress.com/), along with the rest of the ribbon image for the post titles.

I cannot paste the entire code here..., but hopefully you will know what I mean from the site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first two, I'll work on the last now, you needed to locate the `.entry-content` class in your css file.

The first style I added was the `background: #fff;` which added the white background and then I added `border-radius: 7px;` which gives it rounded corners.

```
.entry-content {
   color: #2b2b2b; /* changed to black font since you wanted a white background */
   width: 300px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 0 solid #000;
   margin-left: 10%;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   background: #fff;
   border-radius: 7px;
}
```

For the third question, I am not 100% positive but since you removed the nav on your site I believe you removed the image as well. For some reason on the template page I can not find any styles when you inspect an element. The image is apart of the nav/header area so this is just my best guess.

EDIT: Moving the comment/date block around.

```
.entry-meta {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 150px;
    top: 0;
    left: 35%;
}
```

Comment: Josh,Thanks for this. The .entry-content code worked nicely. I was able to recover the graphic by adding after in the site-header section. However, one more problem I am now having is in this area -

Comment: You're very welcome, if this was the right answer then please make sure to mark it as the answer. :] Best of luck in your design and if you need anymore help then just ask!

Comment: .entry-content,
.entry-summary {
 background-color: #f7f7f7; 
 border: 5px solid #333333;
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 width: 775px;

Comment: If I add the end bracket, it removes the ribbon graphic... any ideas as to why?

Comment: Hmm, let me check it out and see what is going on.

Comment: Code you post in your answer what that line of css looks like?

Comment: it's directly from the css. is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes how the entire block of styles looks exactly from your css. It is a little ruff digging through a wordpress stylesheet.

Comment: also, do you know how i can change the color of the header text?

Comment: That does help and what header text? the blocks that say test2 and etc? or the main header/logo text?

Comment: The main header - The Universal Asian - and the subheader below that. I'd like them to be whitish...

Comment: The two class you need to locate are, `.site-title a` and `.site-description`. Once you found them just change the `color` style to #fff or #ebe8e8 (any color you want) and on the `.site-decription a` class you may want to change the `text-shadow` color.

Comment: That did not work. The text-shadow changed, but somehow the default color is not being overridden...

Comment: Try something like this, `color: #fff!important;`

Comment: Fabulous!!! Any ideas about the closing of the bracket and losing the ribbon graphic? My possibly second to last question is how to stop the posts from 'hovering' scrolling over the header?

Comment: The closing of the bracket I am not to sure on why it is causing that besides a style somewhere may have an extra or lacking an end bracket. For the header, in `.site-header hgroup` you can change `position: fixed;` to `position: absolute;` which will just scroll up. If you want it fixed try adding a `z-index: 10000;` to the class so it will be above the content. I would recommend my first option though and not the z-index/fixed.

Comment: The worked nicely. I will go through the code again and see if there is a bracket that is off. So, two more questions... On the left side, the is the date, comments, edit which come at the bottom of the post. I'd like that to be at the top with the post title. Finally, I'd like to change the font family. Is that just a matter of me looking up different font sets? The original css had some special fonts, but I'd like to choose my own... I really appreciate your help! You've saved me hours!!!

Comment: any thoughts on the last two questions?

Comment: This is the best collection of free to use fonts, http://www.google.com/fonts. It is also very easy to set up and is explained on the site. For moving the options around I can't tell for sure because those are logged in features only. I do see a leave a comment/date link but that is it. Let me see if I can move those around or not.

Comment: Refer to the code I am adding to my answer. You will also have problems on larger titles so I recommend making the `left: 85%;` so it is on the right side but that is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm not finding an extra or missing bracket, but that one bracket seems to be also preventing the date box...

Comment: The last thing I could recommend is to use, http://validator.w3.org/ for validating your html and then http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ to validate your css. This will make it easier to identify where the problem is.

Comment: No problem! Best of luck in your design and I would recommend doing some reading on CSS/CSS3! :]